# Why can't I discuss "Don't convert my cities"?

Tags: civilization-6

Teddy from USA is trying to convert my cities. He has used missionaries to spread religion.

Why can't I see the Discuss option to ask him to stop?

[image]

Comment: Has he activated any missionaries yet, or is he just moving them towards you right now?

Comment: Has activated missionaries. Man, also, what a fight. Wish the military units would act like this.

Comment: He's in a Theocracy.  Perhaps that's impossible for theocracies?

Comment: @joe - France is a theocracy. I can make a demand with them.

Comment: Do you have your own religion? Or are you with other player religion?

Comment: I am Catholic and Ted is Protestant

Comment: Have you ever before told him not to spread his religion?

Comment: @Joe never. he is on a different continent across the ocean and only met him in industrial age I recall.

Comment: So he has definitely already used a missionary on one of your cities? (not sure what you mean by "activated")

Comment: @MichaelCampbell activated = used. Yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't confirmed this, but I believe that you can only bring up this topic of discussion *after* one of your cities has been converted.

Note that using a missionary does not mean your city is converted. Conversion happens when the majority of citizens follow a religion. If a single missionary was used it may be that only some citizens became swayed, but not the majority.

I have found that the AI never brings this up with me until I fully convert at least 1 city.